# Configuring JMS appender with AMQ 5.5.1

Tags: java, jms, soapui, amq

When I am trying to send message from HermesJMS to activeMQ , I am getting thie exception.

```
Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
```

Found out that JMS appender needs to be configured to talk to AMQ as suggested  [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html)

But I am not sure where to add/modify this piece of code in AMQ 5.5.1. Is it log4j.properties file?  Can someone please help?